# In which session/memory does ABAP store static attribute values?

Tags: memory, abap

My guess would be in the ABAP memory from the main session, but I'm not sure and cannot find anything in the documentation. Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this article](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/fc/eb2d40358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm) for the basic memory layout and terminology, unless you already have done so. The static attributes of a class are handled the same way the global variables of a function pool are (you might think of them as global variables of the class pool, but don't hit me too hard for that analogy). Whenever you open a new internal session (e. g. with SUBMIT), they are reinitialized. You could try to check this with a small program that recursively calls itself using SUBMIT ... AND RETURN for yourself.